# Can someone provide me a script to attach to my camera so it will move on touch input?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a 3d game and i want to make the camera move by moving your finger on the screen, its an android game

i searched script on google and i found some but they didnt work... now im using a script but it doesnt behave too good.... if you move your finger from left to right the camera will move as it should but if you keep your finger on the screen and then move the finger from right to left it will keep moving as before for a bit and sometimes it just freaks out ....

here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using UnityEngine;   

public class MoveTouch : MonoBehaviour
{

private Touch initTouch = new Touch();
public Camera cam;

private float rotX = 0.0f;
private float rotY = 0.0f;
private Vector3 origRot;

public float rotSpeed = 0.5f;
public float dir = -1;
private Touch touch;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    origRot = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
    rotX = origRot.x;
    rotY = origRot.y;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            initTouch = touch;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

            //swiping
            float deltaX = initTouch.position.x - touch.position.x;
            float deltaY = initTouch.position.y - touch.position.y;
            if (deltaX != 0)
            {
                rotX -= deltaY * Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed;
            }
            if (deltaY != 0)
            {
                rotY -= deltaX * Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed * dir;
            }
            Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -45f, 45f);
            cam.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0.0f);

        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            initTouch = new Touch();
        }

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your routine is in `FixedUpdate()`.
But Unity docs state that `Input.touches`:

> Returns list of objects representing status of all touches during last frame. (Read Only) (Allocates temporary variables).

All calls to `Input.whateverinputyouareusing` should be in `Update()` that is called every frame. Instead, `FixedUpdate()` is called at regular intervals, sometimes more than once in a single frame (and sometimes it’s not called at all during a frame), and it’s usage is specifically for Physics calculations.